# Strange Firefox icon during Gnome 3.16 upgrade

Tags: gnome, upgrade, firefox, ubuntu-gnome

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04, with Gnome Shell, and 3.16, although I only just upgraded to Gnome 3.16 from Gnome 3.14. And sometime during the upgrade I suddenly noticed this in Firefox:

[image]

It just suddenly appeared before the upgrade was finished (it was in the unpacking stage), and after looking [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-up-firefox-sync?redirectlocale=en-US&as=u&redirectslug=How%20to%20sync%20Firefox%20settings%20between%20computers&utm_source=inproduct) it appears to be something to do with syncing, but I don't use syncing, so what is this? And why did I suddenly get it? Also, after a restart, it has disappeared, and my syncing settings  seam off as usual.

**Information Update:**

It couldn't be related to this in any way now could it: [CVE-2015-4495](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/08/06/firefox-exploit-found-in-the-wild/)?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

**Package Information:**

```
firefox:
  Installed: 39.0+build5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Candidate: 39.0+build5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 39.0+build5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     37.0+build2-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to the bottom of this issue myself, for next time it appeared I clicked on it and it said that I should restart Firefox to install updates (or something like that), so it appears to appear when plug-ins are updated for that was happening at the time.